# How do I git-add with wildcards when ignored files are present?

Tags: git

I'm using msysgit on Windows 7 x64.  I can't figure out how to tell Git to add a lot of files when there are some files that .gitignore might ignore.  For example:

1. Initialize a git repository.
2. Create a .gitignore with contents:

   ```
   *.foo
   ```
3. Create files "test.txt" and "test.foo".
4. Try `git add .`

When I try this, git complains that test.foo is ignored and I should use -f if I really want to add it.  What I'd rather do is add everything *but* the files that are configured to be ignored.  I looked at the git-add documentation and it looks like -A should help; help says, "... and add all untracked files that are not ignored by .gitignore mechanism."  No dice, when I try `git add -A .` I get the same error.  Using -f adds the ignored file, which is not what I want.  (The use case is mass-adding files from a VS project after ignoring .suo and other files.)

Is this a problem with the git implementation I'm using, or is there some argument to git-add that I am missing?

Comment: Note: With Git 2.3.0 (February 2015), `git add --ignore-errors *` would actually work as expected. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28257067/6309). `git add .` remains the recommended way though.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You say *What I'd rather do is add everything but the files that are configured to be ignored* which is exactly what git said it was doing. It added `test.txt` and ignored `test.foo`. It just warned you because the shell expanded the `*` to `test.txt test.foo` so from git's POV you told it to add `test.foo` and it warned you that it didn't add it which is exactly what you wanted. What am I missing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here `git add *` complains, but `git add .` does what is expected  (1.7.0.4, Linux).

From `git-add(1)`:

> The git add command will not add
>   ignored files by default. If any
>   ignored files were explicitly
>   specified on the command line, git add
>   will fail with a list of ignored
>   files. Ignored files reached by
>   directory recursion or filename
>   globbing performed by Git (quote your
>   globs before the shell) will be
>   silently ignored.

Comment: Strange, is there any particular reason why this is the case?  Does the documentation explain how wildcards/directory shortcuts are considered?

Comment: I've added a quote from the documentation describing this behavior.

Comment: This is fine if I want to add all files, but what if I change 10 files, and I just want to add 2. Is it possible to do "git add *.txt" to add all the changed .txt files?

Comment: Why not? *.txt is expanded by the shell.

Comment: Lance: This is perfectly possible - if you want only the text files in the commit, a `git add '*.txt'` will do the trick. You want the quotes to prevent the shell from expanding `*.txt`, then git will zoom through your directory structure looking for matching files and add the txt files to the commit, ref Dan's answer below.

Comment: @ErlendLeganger It might be good to turn this comment into an answer, as it is the simplest solution that actually answers the original question.

Answer (score 13):

Note you can escape more complicated globbing patterns with single quotes as well:

`git add '*test*'`

will allow git to do its own globbing.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to do it is to escape the globbing chars, like this:

```
git add \*
```

Comment: It's good practice to explain a downvote.  This answer also works on my system, and in fact is mentioned in the git-add man page 

"Ignored files reached by directory recursion or filename globbing performed by Git (quote your globs before the shell) will be silently ignored."

Answer (score 2):

Note that [`git add --ignore-errors *`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) would now work, even if some files are ignored.

See [commit 1d31e5a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d31e5a2cd9f90799330d5095783e7b972357f0e) by [Michael J Gruber (`mjg`)](https://github.com/mjg), Git 2.3.0 (February 2015)

> #### `add`: ignore only ignored files
>
> "`git add foo bar`" adds neither `foo` nor `bar` when `bar` is ignored, but dies to let the user recheck their command invocation.
>   This becomes less helpful when "`git add foo.*`" is subject to shell expansion and some of the expanded files are ignored.
>
> "`git add --ignore-errors`" is supposed to ignore errors when indexing some files and adds the others. It does ignore errors from actual indexing attempts, but does not ignore the error "`file is ignored`" as outlined above. This is unexpected.
>
> **Change "`git add foo bar`" to add `foo` when `bar` is ignored, but issue
>   a warning and return a failure code as before the change.**
>
> That is, in the case of trying to add ignored files we now act the same way (with or without "`--ignore-errors`") in which we act for more severe indexing errors when "`--ignore-errors`" is specified.