# Is .gitignore not working or I have misunderstood it?

Tags: git

I am very new to git. I have a .gitignore in the my working folder.

```
*.jpg
*.gif
*.png
system/*
*/Zend/*
.idea/*.*
```

Well, I did `git init` and then `git add *`. At this it worked fine and ignored the above files. But when I did some changes, ran the same command it puts the ignored files into staging area. The reason why I am using `git add *` is because I work on many files and adding each file would be a overkill.

**Update**: Here are messages when I run `git add *` second time..

```
#new file:   application/vendors/Zend/XmlRpc/Value/String.php
#new file:   application/vendors/Zend/XmlRpc/Value/Struct.php
...
```

The list is too long.

Comment: Could you give an example of an ignored file that has been added?

Comment: Have you added the `.gitignore` file & committed it?

Comment: There's no *need* to add and commit

Comment: And if you are modifying too many file you can make use of git status & awk or cut to get only the modified file & add them something like `git status|grep modified|awk '{print $3}'|xargs git add`.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: You are right! My bad.. Dunno what I was thinking :\

Comment: @KurzedMetal: SO i just commit with a nice message?. What does `add` do then?

Comment: That comment was meant for my comment about adding & commiting `.gitignore` file. You have to add & commit for your normal git work flow just as you have been doing.

Comment: @Shubham: `git commit -a` adds+commits all tracked files that have been modified in one action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8527597/422353):

> wildcards in the pattern will not match a / in the pathname

therefore, I think the rule for the `Zend` directory is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

`git add *` should complain if you have a `.gitignore`. See this [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588024/how-do-i-git-add-with-wildcards-when-ignored-files-are-present). I'm not sure why it's not complaining.

Try using `git add .` instead as that's what you really want. Similar problem to this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612630/git-add-all-ignoring-files-in-gitignore).

Comment: I am not sure what i could have done wrong? I checked there is no spelling mistake. Just a fact that I placed `.gitignore` also in my `.git` folder because it was not working.

Comment: I've had weird issues with `.gitignore` not working on Windows before. Have you tried using `.git/info/exclude` instead?

Comment: Well I think I have caught the catch. The new files are getting listed via `git status` which I thought list all staged files but I think it doesn't (may be).

Comment: `git status` should not be showing ignored files: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html And you really should be using `git add .` instead.